# How to know if a file is a storage device in linux

Tags: c, linux, unix, storage, device

I am writing a program that writes partition table to and/or cleans a storage device (*persistent*), may be a SDD/HDD/FDD/USB Flash.

But initially I am using `stat()` to find the details of the `path` argument passed to my code. I am able to identify if the path is a regular or special file using `stat.st_rdev` and  I am also able to find the device's major and minor numbers using `major()/minor()`.

But how can I use this information to distinguish a storage device from any other random device? Is there any range of major/minor numbers to check, between which all devices are one or other type of *persistent* storage device...

Or is there something simpler?

Comment: The majors (and most of the minors) are hardcoded in the kernel, (with a little help from macros, etc) You should not expect them to be the same between versions and distributions, etc.

Comment: please update your Q with the code that is not working. Then people can help recommend a fix for your current problem. Good luck.

Comment: Does it actually matter?  What operations do you intend to perform that you don't want to perform on a regular file, or on a device of some other kind?  What if the file were a disk image?  If your program's behavior is well-documented, then can you not rely on its users to know what they're doing?

Comment: Walk over `/sys/block/*/dev` files and take major/minors from there? Older systems provide similar info in `/proc/partitions`

Comment: man 2 stat, read it. Keyword: S_IFBLK